# Adding and compiling new code in the linux kernel

Tags: compilation, header, kernel

This may sound like a very noob question.
I'm trying to implement a UDP-based protocol in the linux kernel. I was following  the UDPLite protocol implementation as a reference.

Step 1

I created a **new_protocol.c** in **net/ipv4/**
This file has a function

> void _init protocol_init(void){*Code here*}

I also used

> #include "udp_impl.h"

in this file as I was using some functions from the UDP protocol

Step 2

I modified the file **net/ipv4/udp_impl.h** to include **net/new_protocol.h**

Step 3

I created the file **include/net/new_protocol.h** where I defined the function

> void protocol_init(void);

Step 4

Finally, I called the function in **net/ipv4/af_inet.c**. Also, I gave an include statement in this file for **net/new_protocol.h**

Now when I try to build the kernel, I get an error saying

> undefined reference to `protocol_init()'

What am I missing here? Is my way of including header files incorrect? Do I need to include some info in the makefile to pick up the new net/ipv4/protocol.c?

Comment: Side note: if you don't get good answers here; I suggest to identify some linux kernel mailing list or forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to include some info in the makefile to pick up the new `net/ipv4/protocol.c`?

Yes, you need. Kernel build system doesn't autodetect source files, all of them should be listed explicitely in appropriate `Makefile`. In you case you need to modify `net/ipv4/Makefile`.

Makefiles used for kernel build are described in file [Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt).

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add protocol.o in the makefile in net/ipv4/